# Rails take latest child and search by it value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a problem with filtering, in my case I need filter products by value, which locate in children, but I should use only current version, I've already create association with last version via

```
  has_one :product_current_version, -> { order version: :desc }, class_name: 'ProductVersion', foreign_key: :product_id
```

But when I try use

```
Product.joins(:product_current_version).where('product_current_versions.version = 6')
```

It returns error

Thanks for attention, I hope you'll help me

Comment: What error is that?

Comment: #<Product::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x312e94c>
Just error in query

Comment: That is not an error message

Comment: It tell me that query is wrong, in my opinion it's error

Comment: If you want people to help you here you're going to have to be more specific. 'Wrong' and 'error' don't tell us anything.

Comment: Ok, so do you know solution?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have table `product_current_versions` you have a table `product_versions`

```
Product.joins(:product_current_version).where('product_versions.version = 6')
```

Comment: In that case it returns all product which has versions with version 6, even if current version already 55

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
Product.joins(:product_current_version).where(product_current_version: { version: 6 })
```